# Python and reading lines

Tags: python, printing, command-prompt

When i run an .exe file it prints stuff out to the screen. I don't know the specific line of where i want printed out but is there a way I can get python to print the next line after one that says "Summary" ? I know that is in there when it prints and I need the info right after. Thanks!

Comment: can you post some sample code? I don't know if you are running an EXE from Python or if you just want to pass a string to a Python script, or if you are doing something else.

Comment: Not sure seeing sample code would help but when i'm at the command prompt and go into the directory with the exe file and I run it it spits out stuff to the screen. I need to know how in python to print just the line right after Summary to the screen

Comment: Do you already have a Python script executing the EXE? You can grab the output from STDOUT and pass that to the function I posted below.

Comment: Or, can you describe why you want to script python for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really simple Python solution:

```
def getSummary(s):
    return s[s.find('\nSummary'):]
```

This returns everything after the first instance of **Summary**

If you need to be more specific, I'd recommend regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

actually

```
program.exe | grep -A 1 Summary
```

would do your job.

Answer (score 1):

If the exe prints to screen then pipe that output to a text file. I have assumed the exe is on windows, then from the command line:

> myapp.exe > output.txt

And your reasonably robust python code would be something like:

```
try:
    f = open("output.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    # Using enumerate gives a convenient index.
    for i, line in enumerate(lines) :
        if 'Summary' in line :
            print lines[i+1]
            break                # exit early
# Python throws this if 'Summary' was there but nothing is after it.
except IndexError, e :
    print "I didn't find a line after the Summary"
# You could catch other exceptions, as needed.
finally :
    f.close()
```